# pandas read_csv encoding error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have renamed my columns and now the column names come back as:

```
Index([u'Blend', u'Layer', u'Quantity', u'Raw', u'Quantity.1'], dtype='object')
```

the read csv is set to:

```
bulk_data = read_csv('C:\Users\\taerts\Documents\\blends.csv',delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

I tried setting that to the iso encoding and whenever i set that utf-8 to utf-16 i get an error:

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.

My apologies if this is a dumb question, tried all the suggestions i'm finding.
Kinda been swinging and missing.

Comment: post raw input data to reproduce your error, do you have duplicate column names in your csv?

Comment: I can't post the file itself since there could be disclosed info in there. Its a CSV file which comes from an sql query out of showcase data is saved as csv. guess i can try to save it in a different format and just read it like that

Comment: Well my crystal ball isn't powerful enough to guess how your data can reproduce such an error without seeing something I'm afraid, just randomise the data

Comment: You can check if the csv file has a BOM or not but really setting the encoding to 'utf-8' or 'utf-16' should be able to handle it

Comment: Guess i had that coming :), yea tried setting it to utf-8 and 16 but 16 keeps producing an error CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Calling read(nbytes) on source failed. Try engine='python'.

Comment: Did you try setting the engine to python?

Comment: i did resulted in another error. worked around it by subtracting the data in a different way. since i couldnt figure out what i was doing wrong, Thank you guys for helping out btw!